# Why does setting a :first-letter selector with whitespace cause mouse highlighting to be offset?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

Having an issue where by adding whitespace I get the following highlighting offset weirdness. Is this really expected behaviour?

This seems to affect Chrome/Safari

[image: Highlighting weirdness]

Issue is reproduced here: https://jsfiddle.net/qsa99cc6/

CSS:

```css
p:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<p>
         highlight me! this won't work because there's whitespace in the &lt;p&gt;
</p>

<p>highlight me! This should work because there isn't</p>
```

Comment: In Firefox 41 it runs correctly, but I confirmed issue with Chrome.

Comment: it is unusual, but why do you need whitespace in the first place. Can't you use padding-left? What are your constraints?

Comment: The whitespace is an artifact from my build system. I have fixed the issue by removing it, I'm just curious as to why it's happening :)

Answer (score 1):

It's behaviour is different on various browsers. So it could also be some sort of bug in the browser. Maybe those browsers identify the pseudo-element `:first-letter` the same way as the pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after`.

Comment: A pseudo-element isn't not selectable by definition. Pseudo-elements have absolutely nothing to do with selections. There's even a pseudo-element *for* selections, which flies in the face of that definition completely.

Comment: I understand, but my guess is that the browsers might identify it the same way as the unselectable pseudo-elements.